# solr-init Container is unhealthy ( Sitecore Certification Docker Set Up )

Tags: training-certification

I am getting this error when executing

.\up.ps1  ( In Powershell )

ERROR: for solr-init Container "533b5145f4ac" is unhealthy.

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project. ideas ? –

=============================================================

I am trying to follow steps in

Walkthrough: Using the Getting Started template

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

=============================================================

Comment: still no answer to this, this is depressing

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue during the "Run your first Sitecore instance" tutorial and in my case, it was related to the memory usage of the solr image. Try to increase mem_limit of mssql and solr in the docker-compose file and compose again using `docker-compose up -d`.

[image: docker-compose changes]

From the docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/troubleshooting-docker.html#containers-are-stuck-on-created-status_body

Answer (score 0):

do NOT put double quotes in :)  ""[image]

Comment: after running for a few days i am once again getting the same ERROR: for solr-init  Container "244a732b30ed" is unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have solr locally then please stop the service and try again. It might help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the docker container and change `SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME` in `.env` file. Then run `docker-compose up -d` again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I am connected to a workplace VPN. Once I disconnect from the VPN, I no longer get that error.